# jQuery UI is not inherited in ajax loaded content

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter, jquery

I am using CI 2.1.3, having problem with jQuery UI inheritance. Trying to create a ajax gui sortable page nesting.

**view/admin/components/page_head.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="<?=site_url(config_item('path_bootstrap').'css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
  if (!window.jQuery) {
      document.write('<script src="<?php echo site_url(config_item("path_assets")."js/jquery-1.10.1.js"); ?>"><\/script>');
  }
  </script>
  <script src="<?php echo site_url(config_item('path_bootstrap').'js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>

  <?php //if((isset($sortable)) AND ($sortable === TRUE)): ?>
  <!-- script src="<?php echo site_url(config_item('path_jqueryui').'minified/jquery-ui.min.js'); ?>"></script -->
  <script src="<?php echo site_url(config_item('path_assets').'js/jquery-ui.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo site_url(config_item('path_assets').'js/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.jQuery.ui) {
    alert('jquery ui found');
  }
  else {
    alert('jquery ui not found');
  }
  /*if (window.jQuery) {
    alert('jquery found');
  }
  if (window.jQuery.ui) {
    alert('jquery ui found');
  }
  if (window.jQuery.ui.sortable) {
    alert('jquery ui sortable found');
  }
  if (window.jQuery.mjs.nestedSortable) {
    alert('jquery nestedSortable found');
  }*/
  </script>
  <?php //endif; ?>

  <script src="<?php echo site_url(config_item('path_assets').'js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'); ?>"></script>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```

**view/admin/order.php**

```
<section>
  <h2>Order pages</h2>
  <p class="alert alert-info">Drag to order pages and then click 'Save'</p>
  <div id="orderResult"></div>
  <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</section>
<?php dump($sortable); ?>
<script>
$(function() {
  $.post('<?php echo site_url("tutsplus_admin/page/order_ajax"); ?>', {}, function(data)
  {
    $('#orderResult').html(data);
  });

  $('#save').click(function()
  {
    oSortable = $('.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray');

    $('#orderResult').slideUp(function()
    {
      $.post('<?php echo site_url("tutsplus_admin/page/order_ajax"); ?>', { sortable: oSortable }, function(data)
      {
        $('#orderResult').html(data);
        $('#orderResult').slideDown();
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**order_ajax.php**

```
<?php
//dump($pages);
function get_ol ($array, $child = FALSE)
{
  $str = '';

  if (count($array)) {
    $str .= $child == FALSE ? '<ol class="sortable">' : '<ol>';

    foreach ($array as $item) {
      $str .= '<li id="list_' . $item['id'] .'">';
      $str .= '<div>' . $item['title'] .'</div>';

      // Do we have any children?
      if (isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])) {
        $str .= get_ol($item['children'], TRUE);
      }

      $str .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $str .= '</ol>' . PHP_EOL;
  }

  return $str;
}
?>

<?php echo get_ol($pages); ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
    handle: 'div',
    items: 'li',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    maxLevels: 2
  });
});
</script>
```

In order.php jquery, jquery_ui and msj.nestedSortable is succesfully loaded. order_ajax.php is loaded as ajax content. It is not working unless I load jquery ui and msj.nestedSortable script again in order_ajax.php.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script content in a page loaded via AJAX is not beeing executed. Put your script in a *.js-File and load this via [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) or change `dataType` of your AJAX call to `script`:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: "script",
    ...
});
```

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).